# Display Interstitial Add with cordova-admob-pro

Tags: admob, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-admob

I have a cordova app built with Visual Studio and I want to display ads.
I installed cordova-admob-pro plugin.
I tried the following example :
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/test/index.html
and it works perfectly.

But If I changed interstitial Id with mine, it doesn't work, it generates an onAdFailLoad event with the following error :
error=0, reason=Internalerror.

What do I have to do?
Is there something special to do on my Admob account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
You need to enter your payment details and then wait few hours.

Comment: Hi, I've been searching for anyone who has actually got admob pro working with Visual Studio. I'd be very grateful if you could let me know how you got it working in terms of plugin version numbers, edits to gradle files etc.   Here was my question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643547/cant-get-admob-plugin-pro-to-work-with-cordova-in-visual-studio-2017-for-my-and)   Many thanks.